# Permissions defined by fields

Tags: 7, users

I have some content that has state field. I would like to permit users with the **same state** to delete this content.
Can  I implement this in Drupal?
Can I implement it with PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*custom.info*

PS. Do not include <?php ?> tags.

```
; $Id:
name = Custom
description = Custom validate node delete permission
package = Custom
core = 6.x
```

*custom.module*

```
  <?php
    /*
     * file
     */
    function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state< $form_id){
      switch($form_id){
        case 'node_delete_confirm':
          $form['#validate'][] = 'my_custom_validate';
          break;
      }
    }

    function my_custom_validate($form, &$form_state){
      $nid = $form_state['values']['nid'];
      $node = node_load($nid);
      if(/* conditions */) {
        // some procedure to check fields
        $message = t('You have not any permission to delete this node!');
        form_set_error('nid', $message);
      }
    }
  ?>
```

Place this files into `/sites/all/modules/custom/*.*` and activate it on module administration page.
Enjoy.

Comment: thank you for drupal code. but i am not familiar with writing module . can i implement it by php code and delete node with sql.?

Comment: New code has been added

Comment: It's wrong to add a "version" line in .info files; Drupal core modules use such line, but third-party modules should not use it.

Comment: for sure. I'm forget to delete this line